# Cannot modify binary tree node in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary-tree

This is the definition of a binary tree node in JavaScript.

```
 function TreeNode(val, left, right) {
     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
     this.left = (left===undefined ? null : left)
     this.right = (right===undefined ? null : right)
 }
```

I'm currently trying to invert a binary tree. This is the full code.

```
var invertTree = function(root) {
    if(root === null) return null
    else return invertTreeHelper(root, root.left, root.right)
};

var invertTreeHelper = function(node, left, right) {
    if(left === null && right === null) { return node } 
    else if(left === null && right !== null) {
            left = right
            right = null
            invertTreeHelper(node, left.left, left.right)
            return node
    } else if(left !== null && right === null) {
            console.log(right)
            right = left
            console.log(right)
            console.log(node)
            left = null
            invertTreeHelper(node, right.left, right.right)
            return node
    } else {
        console.log("swapping " + left.val + " and " + right.val)
        let temp = left.val
        left.val = right.val
        right.val = temp
        invertTreeHelper(node, left.left, right.right)
        invertTreeHelper(node, left.right, right.left)
        return node
    }
};
```

However, this is the part where I'm having trouble with. Everything else works fine.

```
else if(left !== null && right === null) {
            console.log(right)
            right = left
            console.log(right)
            console.log(node)
            left = null
            invertTreeHelper(node, right.left, right.right)
            return node
    }
```

So in the part shown above I'm trying to swap a null node with a non-null (existing node) but it doesn't seem to modify the original tree because when I print the node after I swapped it, I can see it swapped correctly but the original tree doesn't get modified (it stays null in the original tree). I have tried `node.left` instead of just calling `left` and when I do that it seems to modify the original tree like I want but I'm confused because in the other part of the code as shown below, I'm able to swap the values correctly by just calling `left.val` instead of `node.left.val` and when I print the tree, I see that the values in the original tree were actually modified. So perhaps all I'm asking is why swapping the values with `left.val` without calling `node.left.val` seems to modify the original tree but why swapping the nodes with just `left` without calling `node.left` doesn't. Here is the part where I swap the values and it modifies the original tree.

```
else {
        console.log("swapping " + left.val + " and " + right.val)
        let temp = left.val
        left.val = right.val
        right.val = temp
        invertTreeHelper(node, left.left, right.right)
        invertTreeHelper(node, left.right, right.left)
        return node
    }
```

I'm new to trees so please let me know what I'm missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to assign the returned value - otherwise your recursive function isn't actually working correctly. Maybe this?

```
node = invertTreeHelper(node, left.left, right.right)
node = invertTreeHelper(node, left.right, right.left)
```